# Toolbar Development in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Recently I have developed 2 addins for visual studio. I have already placed them in ToolBar.

When I click on the addin within the toolbar in the visual studio,the addin works normal.
Again when I click on the addin to use it again, it does not Work.In order to make it work I need to close visual studio .So how can I make the addins work without closing visual studio?

***Couple of observations made by me while I was working on this ..***

When I use the Addins, the addin manager(the place where we load the addin by default) checks automatically. So if I uncheck it ,I can reuse the addin without closing visual studio.

But if I do  that it becomes manual operation and the purpose of plugging in addin to toolbar will not be served.

So, is there any way to automatically uncheck the addin in Addin Manager, which gets checked when I run the addin in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to this problem has been found

In every visual Studio Add-in Project there are 5 set of methods.Namely OnConnect,OnDisconnection,OnAddInsUpdate, OnStartupComplete,OnBeginShutdown,Exec,and queryStatus .If visual studio addin logic is written in Exec method,then this problem will be solved.Earlier the problem was caused because add-in logic was written in OnConnect method.OnConnect method is only used to perform some default operation like adding add-in name to toolbar ,which has to be done once while registration.Whereas logic written in Exec is done  again and again,everytime add-in is used, whenever  Add-in button is pressed in toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can happen when the add in has thrown an exception that was not handled.  It can fail silently, which then requires that the add-in be reloaded.